# How to upload flutter dSYM to firebase crashlytics manually?

Tags: flutter, firebase, crashlytics

I have some trace in my Crashlytics dashboard which requires a dSYM to be uploaded for my Flutter app.

I have uploaded manually the output of `/build/ios/archive/Runner.xcarchive/dSYMs/` and it works fine.

However, only the `Flutter` UUID is missing :

```
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1aff94 -[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:].cold.1
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1ac578 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:].cold.2
4  CoreFoundation                 0x14188 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]
5  Flutter                        0x35420 (Missing UUID 4c4c44e755553144a19362a9728e600a)
6  Flutter                        0x3dd800 (Missing UUID 4c4c44e755553144a19362a9728e600a)
```

So after some digging, i have found using a basic python script where was located the `4c4c44e755553144a19362a9728e600a`. It is inside : `UUID: 4C4C44E7-5555-3144-A193-62A9728E600A (arm64) /Users/foxtom/StudioProjects/MyProject/build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter`

Which is a binary file.

So my question is, how do i upload the "dSYM" from this binary ? Or in other words, how to upload manually the Flutter specific dSYMs files ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've got the same error with the same missing dSYM (by UUID). This file doesn't exist on my machine, based on the results of this command:
```mdfind -name .dSYM | while read -r line; do dwarfdump -u "$line"; done```

Which makes sense, if this is coming from pre-compiled code. We started seeing this issue in Flutter 3.10+, and I'm wondering if it is something internal to Flutter.

Comment: I have understood how it works, i will post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have understood the problem and i have made a basic python script to help me find it without the terminal command :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rootdir = '/Users/foxtom/StudioProjects/MyProject/build/ios'
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            os.system(f"dwarfdump -u {os.path.join(subdir, file)}")
```

This will actually print all the dSYM files and IDs i need, then you MUST avoid to run flutter clean otherwise it will wipe out your dSYM since they are located in the `build` folder.

For iOS, you only need to right click on the archive package and `show package content`, then you will find all the dSYM files, compress the ones you want and upload them to crashlytics.

Now, when i build a `release` version of my app, i immediately save the archive somewhere else than the `build` folder of the Flutter project to be able to upload my dSYM later.

Comment: This will never include the referenced dSYM (4c4c44e755553144a19362a9728e600a). The Flutter framework is pre-compiled and a dSYM for it is never built. 

After uploading all the dSYM files from your build, you will still see this dSYM ID missing in crashlytics.

Comment: You probably know this better than i do ! however i do not see any missing dSYM files after doing that in my crashlytics, so far so good

Comment: when you find out the file was `/Users/foxtom/StudioProjects/MyProject/build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter` how do you actually upload the dSYM? do you zip the binary file then manually upload to firebase?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to these issues on Flutter GitHub:

1. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/128018
2. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/127489

The problems stands on Impeller render engine in iOS. Try to go with these [steps](https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/impeller#ios) and disable Impeller engine for iOS app.

This issue was resolved on master branch but was not yet released into stable or beta channel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question is not about the crash in Flutter, it's about uploading the dSYM files to Firebase Crashlytics

Comment: This is probably as good an answer as we can get. Those framework dSYMs aren’t going to exist unless you compile Flutter.framework on your own. Even then it will have a different UUID and wouldn’t match the already uploaded binary.